# Is there an Aurelia equivalent to Angular 2's local template variables?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, aurelia

In `Angular 2` you can create [local template variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#local-vars) to more easily access elements in the html.

```
<input #name type="text">
<button (click)="submit(name.value)">Submit</button>
```

Is there an equivalent functionality to this in Aurelia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes- it's the `ref` attribute.

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=7d1140ba81542bf7a2609a0d09fcdea5

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <input ref="name">
  <button click.delegate="submit(name.value)">Click Me</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  submit(name) {
    alert(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I completely over looked this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Use `ref`

```
<input type="text" ref="name" />

<button click.delegate="submit(name.value)">Submit</button>
```

http://aurelia.io/docs#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/5

Comment: I will add that you should probably use databinding in Aurelia to accomplish getting the name in to the view-model rather than passing it like this.